# IE9 ajax save permission denied

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-9, tinymce, save

IE9 TinyMCE ajax save problem

I have few tabs in one page and in one of the tab i have three textareas(all containing TinyMCE) editors.

I m using ajax to post form and save values and then redisplaying partial view which is returned from the PartialViewResult.

I m using latest version(3.5.8) of TinyMCE.

When i click first time, the textarea values are saved. but when i click second time the tab gets disappeared and gives me 'SCRIPT70: Permission denied'.

The error is occured in tiny_mce_src.js at

```
    getBody : function() {
        return this.bodyElement || this.getDoc().body;
    }
```

I have tried using document.domain = 'localhost'(written at the top of the tiny_mce_src.js), it works but only one textarea convert into TinyMCE editor and the other two remains as proper textarea.

Also tried setting this to 1(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_OBJECT_CACHING\iexplore.exe)

My code for posting form and redisplaying is as follows.

```
    $(".save").live("click", function () {
           tinyMCE.triggerSave();
           var f = $(this).parents("form");
           var action = f.attr("action");
           var serializedForm = f.serialize();
           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: action,
               data: serializedForm,
               async: false,
               cache: false,
               success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                     // redisplay partial view
                     $("div.tab-pane.active").html(data);
                     window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                     InItTinyMCE();
               },
               error: function (req, status, error) {
                     alert("Error occurred!");
               }
           });
           return false;
    });

    function InItTinyMCE() {
           tinyMCE.init({
              mode: "textareas",
              cleanup: true
           });
    }
```

please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to reinitialize the tinymce instances correctly

To shut down an edtor instance use:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'your_editor_id');
```

To reinitialize use

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'your_editor_id');
```

Comment: Means should i first initialize in InItTinyMCE method then remove and reinitialize on success callback?

Comment: no, but it is not clear in your question if the editor instances are getting reinitialized or are located on a tab or something. tinymce does not like being moved around the dom and initializing an editor a second time leads to the behaviour you described

Comment: yes, you are right. i was initializing tinymce two time(first time when the tab loads and second time on success callback). I reduced the initialization of TinyMCE only one time. Now shut down editor and reinitialized when needed any time. thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mode:exact

```
$(window).ready(function() {
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "elm1,elm2"
});

})
```

.................

Comment: I already tried that and it worked also but when i specify document.domain, only one text-area is converted into tinyMCE editor and the other two rendered as proper text-areas.

Answer (score 0):

```
add some line in Sizzle function in sizzle.js like this -

function Sizzle( selector, context, results, seed ) {
var match, elem, m, nodeType,
// QSA vars
i, groups, old, nid, newContext, newSelector;

try{
document === document; //may cause permission denied
}
catch(err){
document = window.document; //resets document, and no more permission denied errors.
}
if ( ( context ? context.ownerDocument || context : preferredDoc ) !== document ) {
setDocument( context );
}
//remaining code will be same 

}
```